# Need help fetching an array using prepared statments

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have wrote the following code to fetch a string. But for some reason its only returning 1.

I have doubled checked everything and it seems like its correct. I am not sure why its only returning 1?

Any help here would be really appreciated!

```
//Class Defined here

   function MenuCat($id){


    $query = "SELECT menu_category_description FROM menu_categories WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($menu_category_description);
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

return $row;

}

$display_category = $cat_des->MenuCat($id);

 echo $display_category
```

Comment: What did you write `->bind_result($menu_category_description);` for, and why isn't the variable used thereafter?

Comment: ahhh. I see that was the problem... I wasn't doing anythign with the $menu_category_description. I tried that and now it worked!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better this way:
First pass in your id as an array (`$id=array("id"=>333)` for example)

Second, change your select statement like this:

`$query = "SELECT menu_category_description FROM menu_categories WHERE id = :id";`

Skip the bind_parm, you don't need it when you pass in an array and your select is set up this way, and execute it this way:

`$stmt->execute($id);`

Comment: Hey Ricky. Thanks for the response. My questions what is the difference between between using the question as place holders and using :id??

Comment: I prefer this method because to me it's simpler to work with and easier to read. Also you don't have to worry about the order of the parameters passed in the array.